# Data Warehousing - OLAP operations

Tags: database, data-warehouse, olap

I would like to know how to find the standard deviation of final scores from a Data warehouse (represented by a schema) representing a universities gradebook using OLAP Operations (slicing,drilling), I cannot post the image for the schema because I don't have enough reputation points.

The schema has the following dimensions:

```
course
student 
semester 
instructor
department
gradebook
```

Could you please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be more specific in your question. Are you talking about a specific product vendor in relation to OLAP databases, Analysis Services, Oracle OLAP, etc? For example, if you are using Analysis Services, the MDX Language has functions ([StdDev](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146068.aspx]) & [StdDevP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146019.aspx])) that would calculate the standard deviation and population standard deviation of an appropriate Set you passed in Oracle likewise doesn't use MDX but has an appropriate function ([STDDEV](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/OLADM/dml_functions_2.htm#OLADM678]))

If more generally you want to understand how to calculate the standard deviation, then you probably understand it's a mathematical formula, that has nothing to do with OLAP and I would recommend Brendan Foltz's excellent, easy to consume, series of videos on broad range of statistical topics if you are interested. There are 3 on standard deviation on his blog [here](http://www.bcfoltz.com/blog/videogallery?tubepress_page=11]) - you will find them in the middle of the select row (Statistics 101: Standard Deviation and NFL Field Goals - Part 1/3, 2/3, 3/3).

Either way, the second will help you understand what to do with the first, once you consult appropriate product documentation.

Comment: It is actually a course that I am taking at the university called business software, and while I was reading the material I came across finding the average of some "CS" courses for example, where the whole data warehouse was represented by a star-schema and then I had to drill-down, slice the CS course grade for all students,hence the slides assumed finding the average, but there was a question which was left opened which asks for finding the standard deviation of final grades from the schema using only OLAP operations.

Comment: This is an example from the slides for finding the average grade for the CS course  
    



    `1- Roll-up on course from course id to department.  
    2- Roll-up on semester from semester id to all.  
    3- Slice for course=“CS”`

Comment: OK. I think I understand what they are trying to ask you, but I have to go out so I'll try and explain later. My thought is they are basically testing your understanding of Star Schemas as opposed to Snowflake Schemas and related things.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your efforts. Looking forward to your explanation.

Comment: Looking at this now, my earlier thoughts were off. So I don't think I'll be able to help out with this much more. The only thing I would say is that knowing that the average grade for CS can be deduced as those 3 operations you have, you can probably infer the average for calculating the variance, as being "variance = (average - drill down member value) squared divided by member count - 1" where standard dev is just the square root of variance, but how you go about describing square roots and squares as olap operations, I will leave for the acedemics...

Comment: ... which I'd love to know if you can find out the right answer from your professor and post back here! Good luck with it and sorry I can't be more help.